# Resultant and independency of a system of polynomial equations

Tags: abstract-algebra, systems-of-equations

Suppose we have 6 polynomial equations with 6 variable where the equations are polynomials over the real numbers of degree 5 and the resultant of each pair of polynomials with respect to every variable is non-zero. Is it true that the system is independent?

Comment: If all equations are the same, then the resultant of each pair would be zero and we assumed that the resultant is not zero...

Comment: OK, then it remains to clarify what the "determinant of the resultant" really is. Usually $res(f,g,x)=\det A(x)$ as in the wikipedia link. So $\det (\det(A(x))$?

Comment: You're right, there's no need to take the determinant of the resultant. The determinant of the resultant is just the resultant itself.

Comment: Alright, edited!